# Have to enter password twice after machine has been on for a couple hours

Tags: login, password

I have a fresh 22.04 install on laptop that will hang on the first login from lock screen after it's been running for a while.
For about an hour or so after bootup it lets me login normally with password or fingerprint and has no issues, but after a while, if I lock it and then I go to log back in, the first login attempt will hang with the spinning icon next to the password box, and I have to press ESC to cancel and then enter my password again and it will login. Also when it starts acting up, it removes my ability to unlock with fingerprint, which works fine when it's not doing this.
I'm fairly new to Linux so I'm not versed on where to look for the issue, but I get no errors or dialog boxes during any of this.

Update: I also just noticed that when this happens, the fingerprint menu disappears entirely from the User settings, as if I don't have a scanner or it's not activated. But it is still turned on in "pam-auth-update"

Comment: This is not a comment it is more info for the question and needs to be added as such with the edit command.